# function only works on server reboot

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that works when running my node server. When refreshing the page a second time it throws an error. When restarting my node server and refreshing the page a third time the function will work again.

I have an array of people

```
const members = [{
    imgUrl: 'resources/members/foobar.png',
    name: 'Foo Bar',
    focus: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
}, {
    imgUrl: 'resources/members/barfoo.png',
    name: 'Bar Foo',
    focus: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
}, {
    imgUrl: 'resources/members/johndoe.png',
    name: 'John Doe',
    focus: [1, 3, 5]
}];
```

and I want to modify this array

```
const targetMembers = members.map(member => {
    member.focus = member.focus.map(skillIndex => skills[skillIndex]).join(', ');
    return member;
});
```

The error I get is

```
TypeError: member.focus.map is not a function
    at members.map.member (C:\Users\...\...\server\routes\main.js:6:37)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at router.get (C:\Users\...\...\server\routes\main.js:5:35)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\...\...\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\...\...\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\...\...\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\...\...\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\...\...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\...\...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\...\...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

and I don't know why this only works on a server reload. I provide a small snippet here

```js
const members = [{
  imgUrl: 'resources/members/foobar.png',
  name: 'Foo Bar',
  focus: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
}, {
  imgUrl: 'resources/members/barfoo.png',
  name: 'Bar Foo',
  focus: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
}, {
  imgUrl: 'resources/members/johndoe.png',
  name: 'John Doe',
  focus: [1, 3, 5]
}];

const skills = [
  'Skill 0',
  'Skill 1',
  'Skill 2',
  'Skill 3',
  'Skill 4',
  'Skill 5'
];

const targetMembers = members.map(member => {
  member.focus = member.focus.map(skillIndex => skills[skillIndex]).join(', ');
  return member;
});

console.log(targetMembers);
```

I store the skills of each member to another array and want to map their skills by the skill key (index) when rendering the template.

Comment: You are changing `focus` from an array to a String. Strings don't have a `map` function

Comment: But why does it work all the time on first try =?

Comment: Because when you first run it, `focus` is still an array. Once you run `const targetMembers = members.map(member...` the `.join()` transforms the array into a String

Comment: Before you do `member.focus = ...` it's an array. After that, you've replaced it with the string that results from `.join(', ')`.

Comment: It seems like you expect this to be operating on a copy of the `member` object. Objects are not automatically copied.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the statement

```
member.focus = member.focus.map(skillIndex => skills[skillIndex]).join(', ');
```

**First Time Execution** - `member.focus` is an `array` and arrays have function `map` and it executes. However, post execution, you have changed **member.focus to a String**.

**Second Time Execution** - `member.focus` is a `String` and String does not have function map and hence, error.

Answer (score 2):

This is most probably a side-effect of mutating the actual property itself, rather than mapping to a new one. If `members` is kept in memory, and somehow attempts to run this again, `focus` is now a string, which does not contain a `map` method.

Map to a new object rather than mutating the existing one:

```
const targetMembers = members.map(member => {
    return {
        ...member,
        focusString: member.focus.map(skillIndex => skills[skillIndex]).join(', ')
   } 
});
```

Comment: If you're making a copy, why use a different property name for the string?

Comment: I guess that's the good approach to "never change the data, add to it". the `focus` property might still be needed in the future.